# Determine the most used single color in an image

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

how do i use code to find out the ratios of the most used color in an image?  Thanks.

Comment: Where did you get stuck? Since you marked this as asp.net, do you have problems with getting a client side picture to the server? Find the color from a pixel, performance, etc. etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best and fastest way to get colors is using [LockBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.DRAWING.BITMAP.LOCKBITS%29;k%28LOCKBITS%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V3.5%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true)

the you can count the colors.

Comment: is this only for bmp images or for any?

Comment: its for all (except indexed images like gif). if you want it to be used for any kind of images, there is a bit slower way (as the bitlock is done in the memory its extremely fast). if you want i can add that solution too.